# How can I make django to write static files list to database when using collectstatic

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

I am storing all the static files in AWS S3 Bucket and I am using Docker containers to run my application. This way, whenever I want to deploy the changes, I create a new container using a new image.

I am running `./manage.py collectstatic` on every deployment because sometimes I add libraries to the project that have static files; and it takes forever to reupload them to S3 on every deployment. Is there a way I can keep a list of static files uploaded to S3 in my database, so that collectstatic only uploads to the added files.

Answer (score 0):

Clean solution would be to read the source for collectstatic and write your own management command that would do the same thing, but would write a file list into the database. A quick and dirty way would be to pipe the output of collectstatic into a script of some sort that would reformat it as SQL and pipe it through a database client.